# Sound:Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I am having an odd issue where my audio file sometimes plays and sometimes does not play.

The catch is that when it decides to not play, the LogCat gives me this message:

```
Should have subtitle controller already set
```

This is my code to play the sound:

```
public void sound(){
    //store the sound file name
    String filename=f_fruit_ar.m4a;

    //All sounds stored in assets folder
    try{
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filename);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();         
        }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your not releasing the resources once player is finished playing you need to release the resources.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public void sound(){
    //store the sound file name
    String filename=f_fruit_ar.m4a;

    //All sounds stored in assets folder
    try{
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filename);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.release();
        }
});
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```